# Inheriting Meta Class in Django Models

Tags: python, django

I have a question as newbie and I am looking for the concept related to inheritance of Meta class in Django classes. Following are the models and I would appreciate if someone can help me.

```
class Base(models.Model):
    code = AutoSlugField(_("Slug"), max_length=128, unique=True,
                         populate_from='name')
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=128, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(_("Description"), blank=True)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField('Country',
                                       blank=True, verbose_name=_("Countries"))
    is_discounted = False
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'shipping'
        ordering = ['name']
        verbose_name = _("Shipping Method")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Shipping Methods")


class OrderAndItemCharges(Base):
    price_per_order = models.DecimalField(
        _("Price per order"), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12,
        default=D('0.00'))
    price_per_item = models.DecimalField(
        _("Price per item"), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12,
        default=D('0.00'))
    free_shipping_threshold = models.DecimalField(
        _("Free Shipping"), decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, blank=True,
        null=True)
    class Meta(Base.Meta):
        app_label = 'shipping'
        verbose_name = _("Order and Item Charge")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Order and Item Charges")
```

Traceback:

```
    class OrderAndItemCharges(Base):
  File "C:\Users\AliKhan\supermarekt\market\shipping\models.py", line 46, in Or
derAndItemCharges
    class Meta(Base.Meta):
AttributeError: type object 'Base' has no attribute 'Meta'
```

I've changed the class import behavior to get over with like following. That might be causing the issue. Reason is that I need to ease the code for dashboard application for the shop. So I imported default Django source for importing Django classes and changed it like below:

```
from django.apps.config import MODELS_MODULE_NAME
def get_class(module_label, classname):
    return get_classes(module_label, [classname])[0]
def get_classes(module_label, classnames):
    if not module_label:
        raise ValueError(
            "Module Does Not Exists")

    market_module_label = "%s" % (module_label)
    market_module = _import_module(market_module_label, classnames)
    return _pluck_classes([market_module], classnames)
def _import_module(module_label, classnames):
    try:
        return __import__(module_label, fromlist=classnames)
    except ImportError:
        __, __, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        frames = traceback.extract_tb(exc_traceback)
        if len(frames) > 1:
            raise
```

Filename is loading.py and I learned it from Django-Oscar. However I made slight changes to tailor it for my need. So might be the issue lie here. Please assist

Comment: It used to work this way. Wondering what may cause this issue...

Comment: I've updated my question above please see if that might help.

Answer (score 53):

You should declare your `Base` class abstract in order to access its `Meta` class as an attribute.

```
class A(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label='yourapp'
        abstract=True

class B(A):
    class Meta(A.Meta):
        db_table='yourtable'
```

Relevant documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance

Comment: The model does not need to be abstract in order to inherit its Meta

Comment: The Basemodel needs to be abstract. As documentation states, the Meta class is only exposed in a Submodel when the Basemodel is abstract. Otherwise you'll get an AttributeError. The Metaclass is also not implicitly inherited. However, the inheriting Model won't automatically be abstract.